# viewing as list in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

Table

```
CREATE TABLE vehicle_details (
    owner_name text,
    vehicle list<text>,
    price float,
    vehicle_type text,
    PRIMARY KEY(price , vehicle_type)
)
```

I have two issues over here

1. I am trying to view the list of the vehicle per user. If owner1 has 2 cars then it should show as owner_name1 vehicle1 & owner_name1 vehicle2. is it possible to do with a select query?
   The output I am expecting

```
      owner_name_1 | vehicle_1
      owner_name_1 | vehicle_2
      owner_name_2 | vehicle_1
      owner_name_2 | vehicle_2
      owner_name_2 | vehicle_3
```

2. I am trying to use owner_name in the primary key but whenever I use `WHERE` or `DISTINCT` or `ORDER BY` it does not work properly. I am going to query price, vehicle_type most of the time. but Owner_name would be unique hence I am trying to use it. I tried several combinations.
   Below are three combinations I tried.

```
      PRIMARY KEY(owner_name, price, vehicle_type) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (price)
      PRIMARY KEY((owner_name, price), vehicle_type)
      PRIMARY KEY((owner_name, vehicle_type), price) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (price)
```

Queries I am running

```
SELECT owner_name, vprice, vehicle_type from vehicle_details WHERE vehicle_type='SUV';
SELECT Owner_name, vprice, vehicle_type from vehicle_details WHERE vehicle_type='SUV' ORDER BY price desc;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your table has:

```
PRIMARY KEY(price , vehicle_type)
```

you can only run queries with filters on the partition key (`price`) or the partition key + clustering column (`price` + `vehicle_type`):

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE price = ?
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE price = ? AND vehicle_type = ?
```

If you want to be able to query by owner name, you need to create a new table which is partitioned by `owner_name`. I also recommend not storing the `vehicle` in a collection:

```
CREATE TABLE vehicles_by_owner
    owner_name text,
    vehicle text,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (owner_name, vehicle)
)
```

By using `vehicle` as a clustering column, each owner will have rows of vehicles in the table. Cheers!

Comment: The input I am providing is (owner_name_1, 'Vehicle1, Vehicle2', SUV, 200000). Will it work for that?

Can I make owner_name primary key as we make in SQL and also use partition, cluster key?